# DRYing out C# for WPF windows with the same fields

Tags: c#, wpf, refactoring, interface, dry

I have two windows in my WPF app:  a login window and an options window.  Both have the same form with a user name and password field, as well as some other fields for providing credentials.  I want some code that knows there will be a `txt_userName` `TextBox` available, for example, and can do things based on that.  I was thinking I could make some kind of `IHaveCredentialsForm` interface and have both `LoginWindow` and `OptionsWindow` implement it, but when I tried, I got "'MyNamespace.LoginWindow' does not implement interface member 'MyNamespace.IHaveCredentialsForm.txt_userName'".  Here's my interface so far:

```
interface IHaveCredentialsForm
{
    TextBox txt_userName { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking I got the error because `LoginWindow` is a `partial` class that inherits from `Window`.  I can definitely access a `TextBox` called `txt_userName` inside the methods of `LoginWindow`, though I haven't explicitly defined such a property.  It magically appeared from having a `TextBox` with that name in LoginWindow.xaml, I assume.

How can I go about DRYing this out?  I already have a method for doing stuff with `string` values for the user name, password, etc., but it seems redundant to have two different classes that are passing in `txt_userName.Text, pwb_password.Password, ...`--the same arguments to the same method.

While I'm at it, how could I share a chunk of XAML (the credentials form) between two different windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could DRY this out by [creating](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpfusercontrol06292008215701pm/wpfusercontrol.aspx) a reusable [user control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/UserControl.aspx) which you could place on both forms.

Comment: Awesome!  I wasn't familiar with user controls (only recently started using WPF).  I implemented your suggestion; that helps my XAML.

Comment: After further refactoring, this helps my C#, too, because I have the .xaml.cs class for my user control to do the work specific to my `txt_userName`, etc. fields.

Answer (score 1):

I would move the logic out of the code behind and into a separate class. Then use data binding to link the properties in the class to the textboxes in the UI.

Something like:

```
//ViewModel class
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

<!--View XAML-->
<TextBox x:Name="txt_username" Text="{Binding Username}" />
<TextBox x:Name="txt_password" Text="{Binding Password}" />
```

This not only will stop you from repeating yourself, but is good practice because it will allow you to test your business logic code separately from the UI.

For WPF a popular design for this type of programming is the MVVM pattern. There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153147/one-sentence-explanation-to-mvvm-in-wpf/1153246#1153246) that will help you grasp the basics, and plenty of tutorials around in the wider web.

After you have moved all the logic out you can create a UserControl that holds the XMAL for the two textboxes (and their bindings) that can be used in both of the views so that you aren't repeating that either.

---

A couple of quick notes with this approach:

- Make sure that you implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your viewmodel to make the binding work
- If you use a PasswordBox in your XAML then there are some [gotchas regarding databinding](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html)