# Reducing Memory Footprint

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, linq

I have a **Main Stream (IEnumerable)** with more than 100,000 items. And then I have multiple `AutoCompleteBox` in my control. All those AutoCompleteBox are bound to the Main Stream.

**First:**

Now the problem is I have around 10 AutoCompleteBox in my control and all having Main Stream as their ItemsSource thus resulting in large memory footprint.

**Second:**

I also need to have a functionality to apply filters on few AutoCompleteBox's ItemsSource at runtime depending upon some events.

I need yours suggestions to reduce this memory footprint and have a functionality to apply filters on runtime.

Comment: 1) Are you using MVVM? 2) Does MainStream is a proeprty with getter which returns a list of items on request/lazy getter, or this is one time populated field/property?

Answer (score 1):

For the memory footprint of the data collection you should look for [Sequential Data Cache](http://sequentialdatacache.codeplex.com/)

Sample to reduce the memory consumption:

```
    public void TestAutoCompleteLookup()
    {
        var path = "";
        using (var c = SequentialDataCache<AutoCompleteItem>.Initialize())
        {
            path = c.Path;

            //add 100.000 items 
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                c.Add(new AutoCompleteItem() { Text = string.Format("{0}Text", i) });
            }

            //query
            var pattern = "1";
            var items = c.Where(autoCompleteItem => autoCompleteItem.Text.StartsWith(pattern)).ToArray();

        }

        if (File.Exists(path))
            File.Delete(path);
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class AutoCompleteItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Memory footprint**

I believe it depends not only from your code implementation but from AutocompleteControlas well, how it uses the bound data source.

- Implement MainStream as calculated property with `yield return` in the getter so items would be calculated/returned on-demand in runtime
- For WPF4 see whether AutocompleteControl using WPF Data Virtualization. Basically you can redefine standard items panel to use `VirtualizingStackPanel` instead of `StackPanel` so framework would allocate memory and create UI elements only for visible items, not for the all bound.

**On-the-fly filtering**

Take a look at the MVVM approach. It would be easily use properties bound to UI filter control to calculate MainSTream items, basically getter would use public bound properties and each time any of those has been changed - MainSTream would recalculate items and notify UI via `INotifyPropertyChanged`, obviously you need to implement support of the `INotifyPropertyChanged`. See [One sentence explanation to MVVM in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1153246/485076)

```
public IEnumerable<IMyItem> MainStream
{
   get
   {
      foreach(var item in mainDataSource)
      {
         if (item.Name == this.NameFilterBoundToUiTextBox)
         { 
            yield return item;
         }
      }
   }
}

private string nameFilter;
public string NameFilterBoundToUiTextBox
{
   get
   {
       return this.nameFilter;
   }
   set
   {  
      if (this.nameFilter != value)
      {
         this.nameFilter = value;

         // TODO: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
         this.OnPropertyChanged("NameFilterBoundToUiTextBox");

         // THis would notify UI to rebind MainSream
         this.OnPropertyChanged("MainStream");
      }
   }
}
```